# Simple image manipulation application

Tags: macos

I apologize in advance if this question does not belong, but .. what software do you use for simple image manipulation on your `mac`?

Tasks I am looking for to do, are no more complicated then:

- Re-size existing image to certain, specific size
- Create image with a certain size

I am working on an `iOS` application and have found out that instead of worrying about how to re-size images, scale them etc .. i should just get images of the size i need (doh!)

I am not looking for things like Photoshop, rather something much simpler (and free if possible)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php?ImageMagick=0afkpa5sss8rsm5ngnh0kkp9c7#macosx) come to mind, with the ability to do batch resize with `convert –resize 800x800 *.jpg` (plus lots of other neat features).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pixelmator](http://www.pixelmator.com/) is a great image editor for OS X if you don't need all the bells and whistles of Photoshop. It's only $30USD, an order of magnitude cheaper than PS, and has a free trial.

I think this is the best choice for beginners or those with more lightweight needs. Because it's Mac only, it integrates with the core technologies of the OS better than even Photoshop does, so it's a very natural learning curve for an OS X user.

However, if you need something totally free, you can also check out the open source [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) project, but this is starting to approach the complexity and power of something like Photoshop.